# MySql ROW_NUMBER not numbering as expected

Tags: mysql

I'm using a query that is using the ROW_NUMBER function and it's not working as I expecting. My understanding of the window functions is that any change in the data will reset the row counter. However it looks like it will resume numbering when it encounters the same combination again. So because (31.7845,-72.52) was found before, row 2267 is '35', not the '1' I was expecting it to be. Is there a way to create this functionality?

```
row_number() over
    (partition by FirebaseUserId, Latitude, Longitude
     order by FirebaseUserId, Id) as 'rownum'
```

[image: actual vs expected]

Comment: Please format your data as _text_, with the full values, so that others may read it.  This looks like a gaps and islands problem, but I can't be certain until seeing clean data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you need to have an incremental number order by `Id` only and reset it once any of `FirebaseUserId`, `Latitude`, `Longitude` changes. Built in `ROW_NUMBER()` won't work this way. You can use a variable to implement such a customized logic.

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    lag(FirebaseUserId) over w FirebaseUserId_prev,
    lag(Latitude) over w Latitude_prev,
    lag(Longitude) over w Longitude_prev
  from tabledata
  window w as (order by Id asc)
)
select Id, FirebaseUserId, Latitude, Longitude,
  case when FirebaseUserId = FirebaseUserId_prev and Latitude = Latitude_prev and Longitude = Longitude_prev then @rownum := @rownum + 1 else @rownum := 1 end rownum
from cte
join ( select @rownum := 0 ) r
order by Id asc
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b3e50199be8e2ddec9609e0ed536b43)

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

(This may be just *part* of an answer, but I think it's easier to read than in comments and therefore warrants an answer.)

You've got three partitions (I cannot copy/paste from an image, so I cannot list them for you). So you got three number ranges.

In each partition the number starts with `1` (there seem to be a lot of rows from the result missing in your post though?) and increment by the order given in `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause (not (necessarily) by the order of the rows in the (final) result, which is probably what you thought?). (BTW, `FirebaseUserId` in the `ORDER BY` is useless -- it's the same for all rows in a partition because it's part of the `PARTITION BY`.)

So yeah, `2267` is in the same partition as `2265` and comes directly after it, so the `row_number()` is increased by `1` to `35` because it was `34` for `2265`.

There is no "reset" because the partitions are the same.

To get a solution for what you actually want, it's best if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70602177/edit) the question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.